# Id auto increment varchar not increments

Tags: sql-server

I am using a `VARCHAR` column as my primary key. I want to auto increment it (base 62, lower/upper case, numbers), However, the below code fails (for obvious reasons):

```
CREATE TABLE TESTING
(
    ID VARCHAR(10),
    NAME VARCHAR(15),
    DESCP VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Creating a procedure for testing insert of a new record with `NVARCHAR` auto-incremented ID:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_INSERT 
     @NAME VARCHAR(MAX), @DESCP VARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN
    /* Logic for getting new ID as per the NAME with PRE FIX */ 
    DECLARE @NEWID VARCHAR(5);
    DECLARE @PREFIX VARCHAR(10); 

    SET @PREFIX = UPPER(SUBSTRING('STR', 1, 3)) 

    SELECT @NEWID = (@PREFIX + replicate('0', 3 - len(CONVERT(VARCHAR, N.OID 1))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, N.OID + 1)) 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             CASE 
                WHEN MAX(T.TID) IS NULL
                THEN 0 ELSE MAX(T.TID) 
             END AS OID 
         FROM 
             (SELECT SUBSTRING(ID, 1, 1) AS PRE_FIX,
                     SUBSTRING(ID, 2, LEN(ID)) AS TID 
              FROM Testing) AS T 
         WHERE 
             T.PRE_FIX = @PREFIX) AS N
   /* INSERT QUERY FOR NEW RECORD */
   INSERT INTO Testing VALUES (@NEWID, @NAME, @DESCP)
```

END

I try to insert a values:

```
SP_INSERT 'svce','YOUR MANAGEMENT DESCRIPTION';
```

this first time, again try to inset I got same ID is not incremented.

Like:

```
ID     Name
------------
SVC001 SVCE
SVC001 Svce
```

Comment: You will always encounter problems when re-inventing the wheel. Either Use a simple int identity column as your primary key or a combination of columns that is unique per row. Create that varchar value either in select or as a computed column.

Comment: Be aware that in most cases, primary keys have the clustered index of the table. It is best practice to keep the clustered index as small as possible for performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `COMPUTED COLUMN` something like that:

```
create table t
(
    Id int auto_increment,
    ComputedId as 'SVC' + convert(nvarchar(60), lpad(Id,3,'0')),
    Data nvarchar(60)
)
```

Comment: I already tried this but i can't able to set primary so that only I moved that code if any other suggestion give me please

Answer (score 0):

I MADE ONE SMALL SCRIPT,

```
declare @t table (id varchar(10))
insert into  @t values ('SVC001'),('SVC20902')
Declare @NEWID int
select @NEWID=isnull(max(replace(id,'SVC',''))+1,1) from @t

select 'SVC'+ replicate('0',CASE WHEN 3-len(@NEWID)<=0 
THEN 0 ELSE 3-len(@NEWID) END)+cast(@NEWID as varchar(10))
```

Comment: This actually worked but I want to increment a ID value automatically

Comment: if it work then you can put the logic in UDF and call the UDF in computed column.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution for Auto_Increment ID. I done following code for solution. code is:

```
alter PROCEDURE SP2_INSERT
      @NAME VARCHAR(MAX),
      @DESCP VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @NEWID VARCHAR(10);
      DECLARE @PREFIX VARCHAR(MAX);
   SET @PREFIX = UPPER(SUBSTRING(@NAME,1, 3))

   SELECT @NEWID = (@PREFIX + replicate('0', 3 - len(CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.OID + 1))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.OID + 1)) FROM (
   SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(T.TID) IS null then 0 else MAX(T.TID) end as OID FROM (
   SELECT SUBSTRING(EmployeeID, 1, 1) as PRE_FIX,SUBSTRING(EmployeeID, 2, LEN(EmployeeID)) as TID FROM EmployeeMasters
 ) AS T WHERE T.PRE_FIX = @PREFIX
) AS N
INSERT INTO Testing VALUES (@NEWID,@NAME,@DESCP)
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(ID VARCHAR(10),
 NAME VARCHAR(15),
 DESCP VARCHAR(50))

DECLARE @NEWID VARCHAR(5);
   DECLARE @PREFIX VARCHAR(10); 

SET @PREFIX = UPPER(SUBSTRING('STR', 1, 3)) 

 SELECT @NEWID=CAST(ISNULL(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ID,4,LEN(ID)) AS INT)),0)+1 AS varchar) FROM @table
 INSERT INTO @table(DESCP,ID,NAME)
 SELECT 'zzzz',(@PREFIX + replicate('0', 3 - len(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@NEWID))))+@NEWID,'fsf'

 SELECT @NEWID=CAST(ISNULL(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ID,4,LEN(ID)) AS INT)),0)+1 AS varchar) FROM @table
 INSERT INTO @table(DESCP,ID,NAME)
 SELECT 'zzzz',(@PREFIX + replicate('0', 3 - len(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@NEWID))))+@NEWID,'fsf'

 SELECT * FROM @table
```

Comment: "Try this," is not an answer. Explain what problem you perceived with the OP's code, what changes you propose and why that will fix the problem.

Comment: ok @Doney but I not need to repeater a select, insert query because i want to use in a project so please tell me how can I select a ID increment value

Comment: @Meena S It need only one select insert into values is also possible...    values ( 'zzzz',(@PREFIX + replicate('0', 3 - len(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@NEWID))))+@NEWID,'fsf')